# Dynamically growing Command Table Implementation

Tags: c

I need a data structure to store a list of single commands that a user can enter. You may consider a simple shell. I already finished the parsing but need a nice data structure to store the individual commands.

Consider the following example:

A user inputs something like this:

```sh
>>> ls -l | wc -c && echo "Hello World";
```

This is a single line with multiple commands that are executed sequentially. Because there are pipes, redirects, reads and so on I would like to encapsulate the command with all of its properties into a separate structure.

The above would become something like:

1. Command: `ls -l` which creates a pipe
2. Command: `wc -c` which reads from a pipe
3. Command: `echo "Hello World"` with no I/O at all

I came up with the following solution. While this works it feels somewhat complex and I feel like I am missing some obvious, much more simplistic approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZ 4

struct SingleCommand
{
    // Currently preallocated space
    int allocated;

    // Current number of stored args
    int nargs;

    // Arguments
    char **args;

};

typedef struct SingleCommand SingleCommand;

SingleCommand create_single_command()
{
    SingleCommand command;
    command.nargs = 0;
    command.allocated = BUF_SIZ;
    command.args = malloc(command.allocated * sizeof(char *));
    if (command.args == NULL)
    {
        /* Fatal memory error */
        exit(-1);
    }
    return command;
}

void free_single(SingleCommand *command)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < command->nargs; i++)
    {
        free(command->args[i]);
    }
    free(command->args);
}

void insert_arg(SingleCommand *command, char *arg)
{
    if (command->nargs + 1 >= command->allocated)
    {
        /* Grow allocated space */
        command->allocated += BUF_SIZ;
        command->args = realloc(command->args, command->allocated * sizeof(char *));
        if (command->args == NULL)
        {
            /* Fatal memory error */
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    command->args[command->nargs++] = strdup(arg);
}


struct ComplexCommand
{
    // Currently preallocated space for single commands
    int allocated;

    // Current number of stored single args
    int n_single_args;

    SingleCommand **commands;

    char *out_file;

    // Current index in execution chain
    int current_command;

};

typedef struct ComplexCommand ComplexCommand;

ComplexCommand create_complex_command()
{
    ComplexCommand command;
    command.n_single_args = 0;
    command.allocated = BUF_SIZ;
    command.current_command = 0;
    command.commands = malloc(command.allocated * sizeof(SingleCommand *));
    if (command.commands == NULL)
    {
        /* Fatal memory error */
        exit(-1);
    }
    return command;
}

void free_complex(ComplexCommand *command)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < command->n_single_args; i++)
    {
        free_single(command->commands[i]);
    }
    free(command->commands);
}

void insert_command(ComplexCommand *command, SingleCommand *single)
{
    if (command->n_single_args + 1 >= command->allocated)
    {
        /* Grow allocated space */
        command->allocated += BUF_SIZ;
        command->commands = realloc(command->commands, command->allocated);
        if (command->commands == NULL)
        {
            /* Fatal memory error */
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    command->commands[command->n_single_args++] = single;
}

int main()
{
    // This would normally be generated by my parser
    SingleCommand single1 = create_single_command();
    insert_arg(&single1, "ls");
    insert_arg(&single1, "-l");

    SingleCommand single2 = create_single_command();
    insert_arg(&single2, "wc");
    insert_arg(&single2, "-c");


    SingleCommand single3 = create_single_command();

    // Such a complex command would be created after parsing the input line
    ComplexCommand complex = create_complex_command();
    insert_command(&complex, &single1);
    insert_command(&complex, &single2);
    insert_command(&complex, &single3);


    // I can then iterate over it and execute each command
    SingleCommand cur;
    while (complex.current_command < complex.n_single_args)
    {
        cur = *complex.commands[complex.current_command++];
        printf("<SingleCommand:: Allocated: %d , Nargs: %d, Command: ", cur.allocated, cur.nargs);

        // Concat args:
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.nargs; i++)
        {
            printf("%s", cur.args[i]);
        }
        printf(">\n");
    }

    // Cleanup;
    free_complex(&complex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A common allocation scheme is to allocate some even multiple of `_Alignof(type)`, in this case a char pointer. Then when you run out of memory as the container grows, you reallocate twice the previous amount. That's how various C++ STL classes were implemented back in the days, though if there's any computer science (other than "aligned is good") backing up that algorithm, I don't know.

Comment: You write that `ls -l` creates a pipe and that `echo` doesn't output anything ("no I/O"). That contradicts the operation of these programs and commands when you invoke them in a typical shell. There, they all generate output and some consume input. Creating the pipe connecting the frist two is done by the shell there. Care to clarify?

Comment: @uli With no I/O I mean that my shell does not has to handle anything besides opening a new process and executing the program. If there are pipes or redirects I need to take care of that in my shell implementation.

Answer (score 3):

- **`int current_command;`**

  I strongly advise against it. It is not the property of `ComplexCommand`. It is a property of whoever deals with it. Consider instead

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < complex.n_single_args; i++) {
      ....
  }
  ```
- **`realloc`**

  - A missing `* sizeof(SimpleCommand *)` in

    ```
    command->commands = realloc(command->commands, command->allocated);
    ```

    is certainly a bug. You add that many *bytes*, rather than `SimpleCommand *`s.
  - As long as you immediately `exit` on failure, it is OK to do a simple assignment. In the real life a naive realloc may lead to memory leaks. You need to be more prudent, e.g.:

    ```
    temp = realloc(command->commands, command->allocated);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        // Now you have a chance to do a cleanup
        ....
    } else {
        command->commands = temp;
    }
    ```
- An argument to `sizeof` is better expressed in terms of variables, rather than their types. It avoids the double maintenance problem it the type of variable ever changes. For example, prefer `sizeof(*command.commands)` to `sizeof(SimpleCommand*)`.